# jquery ui autocomplete: how to cancel slow ajax request after text input loses focus

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using an JQuery UI Autocomplete field that is tied to an ajax lookup that can be rather slow at times.  Occasionally a user will tab away from the text input field *after* the ajax query initiates but **before** the ajax call returns.  When this happens,  the autocomplete pop-up appears even though the text input no longer has focus, and the only way to dismiss the popup is by selecting an item (rather than tabbing to another field).

In fact, this [jquery ui demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) exhibits the same behavior (for example enter 'ariz' into the text field,  wait for the 'searching' animation to appear and then tab out of the field before it returns any results).

One solution that works (but feels like a hack) is to check in the ajax's success callback to see if the text field still has focus, and if not to call response() with an empty list, for example:

```
        $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        var elem = this.element;
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                data: {name_startsWith: request.term},
                success: function( data ) {
                    if(!$(elem).is(':focus') {
                        response({});
                        return;
                    }
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there a more graceful solution?  Ideally I'd like to cancel the ajax request as soon as the user tabs away from the text input field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$.ajax` returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object and that object exposes the [`abort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) of the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object. So, you just need to stash the `jqXHR` and abort the request at the right time. Something like this perhaps:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $element = $(this.element);
    var jqXHR = $element.data('jqXHR');
    if(jqXHR)
        jqXHR.abort();
    $element.data('jqXHR', $.ajax({
        // ...
        complete: function() {
            // This callback is called when the request completes
            // regardless of success or failure.
            $this.removeData('jqXHR');
            // And dismiss the search animation.
            response({});
        }
    });
}
```

And then you'd want some stuff on `#city`:

```
$('#city').blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var jqXHR = $(this).data('jqXHR');
    if(jqXHR)
        jqXHR.abort();
    $this.removeData('jqXHR');
});
```

There is a brief blur/focus sometimes during the autocompleter's normal operation but that only happens when when someone chooses something from the list; there shouldn't be a `$.ajax` request running when that happens so we don't need to worry about it. If I'm wrong then you can kludge around it by using a timer inside the `blur` handler and cancelling the timer in a `focus` callback (you could store the timer-ID in another `.data()` slot too).

I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: This is great! It got me 95% there, just a couple issues:  1) in the source anonymous function,  'this' is the autocomplete object, not the element -- use 'this.element'.  once i did this the data binding worked.  2)  in the complete anon function,   add a "response({})" do dismiss the search animation.    Besides that,  this is perfect.  thanks so much!

Comment: fyi:  I added an 'edit' to your answer but I don't have edit rights.  I'm not sure if you can accept the edits or if a 'peer reviewer needs to'. Otherwise once this edit is in I can mark this answer correct.

Comment: @NobodyMan: Sorry about that, I just wrote it off the top of my head. I had to tweak your edit a bit to get it approved right away (otherwise we'd have to wait for two people approve it) so I moved the comment.

Comment: One small note. You fire response({}); in any case it actually collapsed my loaded autosuggestion items. So I've modified complete

              `complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    // This callback is called when the request completes
                    // regardless of success or failure.
                    $this.removeData('jqXHR');
                    // And dismiss the search animation.
                    if ('success' != textStatus && 'notmodified' != textStatus) {
                        response({});
                    }
                }`