# How to cancel an ajax request in Django when new page is requested

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

In my web page (built on the Django platform), I have some jQuery that requests server data via an ajax request. How do I prevent the error function from executing when I click away from the page before the ajax request has responded.

Here is my jQuery call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax( {
    url:'/server/url/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {some..data},
    success:function(response) { do stuff with response },
    error: function() {alert('error')}
});
```

How do I prevent the alert from happening when I click away from the page (to a new page)?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7748794/1114171) answer for some inspiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a global variable:

```
var ajaxcancel = false;
```

No you need to make that `true` if user closes the window:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
    ajaxcancel = true;
});
```

And change the ajax error line to check for the value of that variable first:

```
...
error: function() {if (!ajaxcancel) alert('error'); }
...
```

Comment: Could I just call xhr.abort() in the $(window).unload(function() {});?

Comment: First let's correct my code; you'd better NOT use the unload event function here ([it's very browser-dependent](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)). Instead you can bind the `beforeunload` event to your window (and don't return anything in that function). As of jqXHR's abort, I tried with Firefox and it still raised the error. BTW someone please downvote me and make my score 0...

Comment: @Hossein: You can just delete the answer, or edit it to be correct.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot cancel a sent AJAX request but what you can do (as I think this might be applicable to your situation) is when leaving the page that made the request, you can make another AJAX request to cancel the previous operation kicked off by the initial AJAX request. This may help your case if the AJAX request you made starts off some expensive reporting or database or algorithmic operation on your server side.

At least you can let the server know not to waste any more resources since the user has moved on.