# Prevent Django exception when navigating away from page during long running AJAX call

Tags: jquery, django, exception, python-2.7

In my application, I fire off an Ajax get request using Jquery on page load. If the call takes an unusually long time, the user may navigate away from the initial page during their standard browsing session. Eventually, this ajax call completes and fires a response back. The problem is, by this time the user has left the page and nothing is listening for a response any more. I get this exception in my logs when that occurs.

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('98.x.x.x', 36495)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\Python2.7\App\lib\SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "M:\Python2.7\App\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "M:\Python2.7\App\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "M:\Python2.7\App\lib\SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "M:\Python2.7\App\lib\SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "M:\Python2.7\App\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

None of the files listed in the exception are my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only happen when you use the django development server, which tries to log exceptions on the console.

However, with other webserver (like apache) you will get similar exception but probably not so  much descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

This question is functionally identical to [How to cancel an ajax request in Django when new page is requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005111/how-to-cancel-an-ajax-request-in-django-when-new-page-is-requested) and the answer is the same.